# Creating new servlet in eclipse kepler for maven web app project

Tags: eclipse, maven, web-applications, eclipse-kepler

I created simple maven web application project. After creation there were no 'src/main/java' and 'src/test/java' folders but only 'src/main/resources'.
I added this two folders and updated maven project.

Than I added some package to 'src/main/java' and try to add servlet by right click at package element

[image]

At next step I see window with some servlet details

[image]

But when I start to add servlet name eclipse shows me message that "Not a java source folder". 
By the same way I can add simple class to this pachage without any problem but in case of servlet I cannot. Do I miss something during configuration?

Comment: Did you try Browsing to select the (same) source folder that way?

Comment: What Browsing do you mean? On disk folders are created, if I add class by eclipse it is added, inside jar I see it after build.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the cause of the problem, but I solved it restarting Eclipse (I have Eclipse Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)).