# Random "not a Java source folder" in Eclipse Maven Projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I create new Maven Projects with Eclipse I *sometimes* have the error "servlets/beans is not a Java source folder" when I create my first class in the folders src/main/java/beans or src/main/java/servlets.

It happens totally randomly and if I create several projects with exactly the same procedure I finally manage to have a project that doesn't have this problem.

The solution I found to not have to create several projects is to declare the servlets/beans folders as java source. But it's not perfect because my classes are not in packages, so my code is not directly shareable and I can't use some Spring functionalities. It seems that a solution could be in the "Java Build Path" but I didn't manage to make it work.

This problem happens from years across several Eclipse or Java versions (also Tomcat versions but it doesn't seem related).

Do you have an explanation about why this problem appears (the most surprising is that it happens randomly) or an other solution than "use as Java Source" ?

Comment: Can you show us the error in the UI? One solution would seem to be to put your classes into packages, as src/main/java is *the* Java source folder Maven expects.

Comment: @nitind There is a capture from an other similar question in SO : https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNpjG.png

Comment: Lol, I just saw that you already was in the commentaries of this question 6 years ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107628/creating-new-servlet-in-eclipse-kepler-for-maven-web-app-project

Answer (score 0):

BY default maven takes `src/main/resources` as the resources root. You can try define the `resources` directory of the project with this maven plugin.

```
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>[your folder here]</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
```

Or else, you should be probably do this in Eclipse UI from right click on the directory and set as Source Directory Root. (As it is in Idea)

Answer (score 0):

Try this - Right click the Maven Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
In Order and Export tab, you can see the message like '2 build path entries are missing'
Now select 'JRE System Library' and 'Maven Dependencies' checkbox